# HTAccess Rewrite affecting other files in the Root?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm on a 1and1 shared server containing my other websites.

In the Root I have an HTAccess file Rewriting a photo viewing php file with an ID as a parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)\.html?$ /photography/albums/viewphoto.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Example:
    Current URL:
    http://www.example.com/photography/albums/viewphoto.php?id=C01-A01-P01

```
Desired URL:
http://www.example.com/C01-A01-P01.html
```

All works for the rewrite of the URLs, but the html files located in the root have stopped including my PHP code functions and variables held in an .inc file.

Am I missing something in making the rewrite specific to a single file or is an option missing on the rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a RewriteCond to exclude existing files from the Rewrite ,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?$ /photography/albums/viewphoto.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```